# Reason why I can't insert a comment inside the HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html

Are there any reason why I can't insert a comment inside the HTML tag?

**Sample: In HTML (Not Possible)**

```
 <img <!-- sample comment--> src="" alt="Sample Picture" class="img-circle center-block" />
```

While in JavaScript it can be easily done.

**Sample: In JS (Possible)**

```
verticalCentered: /* Sample Comment*/ true
```

Please explain it in a detailed way.

Comment: Think of the comment tag as another regular tag. You wouldn't but an image tag inside an image tag, or an anchor there, would you?

Comment: Ultimately, the reason why you can't do it is "because W3C decided you can't". There is a reasoning behind it that justifies that decision, but the only bit that pertains to a designer/programmer is just the fact that it doesn't work.

Comment: Are there any special reason why you want to insert a comment inside the HTML tag? If no then you should stick to inserting a comment outside the HTML tag.

Comment: I'm just curious. Because in other language we can easily get it done. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML was originally defined formally as an application of SGML, and the comment syntax was taken from SGML. SGML uses two hyphens `--` as comment delimiters, but it permits comments in certain contexts only. Of these contexts, only a comment declaration is relevant in HTML. (Well, in theory they are also allowed in entity declarations like `<!ENTITY foo "foo" -- Comment -- >`, but entity declarations were never implemented in any browser before XHTML, and in XHTML, following XML syntax, entity declarations cannot contain comments.)

Thus, comments are only allowed in comment declarations that contain nothing but comments, e.g.

```
<!-- Comment one -- -- Comment two -->
```

Browsers actually implemented this partly in a simplified (wrong) way, so the practical recommendation is to have comments only in comment declarations that contain a single comment:

```
<!-- Comment -->
```

Comment declarations are at the same structural level as tags and therefore cannot appear within tags. (Comments cannot contain tags either: anything that would otherwise constitute a tag, like `<p>`, is taken just as character data when inside a comment.)

This has not been changed in later HTML versions. They have simplified the syntax in matters like this, not extended.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a templating language, you may be able to use the templating language's comment mechanism to do what you want: `<img {{! this is a comment }} src=...`. This also has the advantage that the comment will be removed at compile time, and thus won't litter your HTML with comments.

Comment: What is the best templating language? This is a good suggestion @torazaburo.

Comment: Thanks! By templating language you mean django, jade, etc. right?

Comment: Django is not a templating language per se (although it has one). Jade is a templating language primarily used on the server side; Handlebars is a well-known client-side templating language.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Torazaburo. I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: If you interpret the question as "Can I put an **HTML** comment in the middle of the tag", then you're right, no, it doesn't. But that's not what the question says, it says, "How can I put a comment (*of some kind*) in the middle of a tag", to which the answer is, You can, if you're using a templating language and it permits comments there. Since the OP himself said "This is a good suggestion", the notion that we should apply some kind of strict constructionism or original meaning analysis to the questions seems a bit, well, misplaced.

Comment: The question asks for a reason and is limited to HTML (JavaScript is mentioned just for comparison). Whether some comments that do not answer the question are welcomed by the OP is not relevant in deciding whether this is an answer in SO terms. Answers that do not answer the question are distracting to people who search SO for answers to *their* questions and find a question that (as asked) matches theirs.

Comment: We'll agree to disagree.

Answer (score -2):

Because comment is also a tag & you can not write html tag inside anther html tag.

Comment: A comment is not a tag. It's a comment node. So to be pedantic what you want to say is "a tag cannot contain HTML nodes".

Comment: but w3schoools described it as tag. can you share any links with more clarification?

Comment: To be precise (which w3schools never is), a "tag" is the sequence of characters `<a>` or `</a>` ("end tag" and "start tag'), and the `a` is the "tag name". The entire sequence of start tag, content, and end tag is an "element". An element is one particular type of "node"; comments are another. W3schools uses the term "tag" in a non-standard and confusing way, to refer to different types of elements plus things like comments and doctype declarations. Just another reason to avoid that site like the plague.

Comment: Indeed so. From HTML5 spec: "Tags are used to delimit the start and end of elements in the markup." There are only start tags (`<a>`) and end tags (`</a>`); Comments are no tags of any kind, but they are nodes.

Answer (score -6):

You can insert a comment into html tag. If im using a netbeans then you can disable HTML error checking when the error appears

Comment: You *can* but it's invalid and breaks html

Comment: There's a fun joke, goes like this: "Why can't I eat death cap mushrooms?" "You can, but usually only once." If you put comment into a HTML tag, it's not HTML any more.