# why comments not working inside <img> tag in HTML

Tags: html

This is weird, I just found my code in HTML not working

```html
<img
            src="animal-chihuahua-cute-39317.jpg"
            align="center"
            border="3"
            hspace="50"
            vspace="10" <!--attribute indicates amount of space to the top and bottom on the image-->
            alt="doggy"
            width="250"
            height="250"
        />
```

I also read an article on StackOverflow: [Reason why I can't insert a comment inside the HTML tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374090/reason-why-i-cant-insert-a-comment-inside-the-html-tag)

still not clear with the explanation. Can someone help me with this!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a tag inside a tag attribute list. `<` aren't parenthesis: you can't nest them, you need to close one before you open another. Comments in html are like all other tags, except they are not interpreted and displayed by the browser, and as such they must adhere the rules of all tags

All language have rules for where comments can and cannot be placed. You normally can't use a comment in a quoted string literal for example. Some language restrict you to comment only at the end of the lines. Some don't allow comments inside other comments. HTML don't allow them inside tag declarations (between `<` and the corresponding `>`). Just accept it.

Comment: thats helpful, thanks @pqnet

Comment: I very much appreciate your answer @pqnet, its really helpful and now I understand on of a core concept in html. thanks again.